# iOS internationalization storyboards not showing

Tags: ios, internationalization

I'm working on an application that needs to be multilingual.

I am attempting to follow [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html) tutorial on internationalization. However, when I attempt to 'use Base Internationalization', none of my storyboards are listed in the view.

I'm using XCode 4.6.3

Am I missing something here, or should I be taking a different approach?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So here is what needs to be done.

Open the storyboard(s) that you want to localize. In the utilities pane (right hand side), select 'Show the File Inspector'.

About halfway down that list of options, there is a button labeled 'localize'.

After pressing that button, that storyboard will appear in the list after pressing 'Use Base Internationalization.